# SSL Support for PHP 5.3.3 and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, ssl, pdo

After a solid day investigating why I can't get my application to connect to a remote server over SSL using PHP PDO, I found PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL..., but it seems that they exists only for 5.3.7 or above.

My Question is this. Is SSL support only available for PHP 5.3.7 and above? Or am I incorrect in my conclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According documentation ssl support is introducing in 5.3.7.

**Change log:**

> - 5.4.0  MySQL client libraries 4.1 and below are no longer supported.
> - 5.3.9  Added SSL support with mysqlnd and OpenSSL.
> - 5.3.7  Added SSL support with libmysqlclient and OpenSSL.

and properties are only available y 5.3.7 or above.

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA (integer)

    The file path to the SSL certificate authority.

    This exists as of PHP 5.3.7.
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CAPATH (integer)

    The file path to the directory that contains the trusted SSL CA certificates, which are stored in PEM format.

    This exists as of PHP 5.3.7.
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT (integer)

    The file path to the SSL certificate.

    This exists as of PHP 5.3.7.
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CIPHER (integer)

    A list of one or more permissible ciphers to use for SSL encryption, in a format understood by OpenSSL. For example: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA

    This exists as of PHP 5.3.7.
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY (integer)

    The file path to the SSL key.

    This exists as of PHP 5.3.7.
```

Se also: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 2):

For SSL Support you have to enable the *php_openssl* module. Otherwise you haven't the libs to make a connection. Here the same with *file_get_contents* for example.

Check if the module is activated and openssl is installed.

if you use a linux system you can install the module over the package manager.

Comment: openSSL is installed, and working. The code works with a local database, and a remote using an older driver, but not remote using PDO.

Comment: Do you have a Firewall on your Server?